# Edhesive says my program does not pass all tests

Tags: java

The goal of the program is to test if a integer value input from the keyboard is equal to 176. If it is, print "YES" (without the quotes).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lesson_11_Activity_One {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(" Please enter a number :");
        int number = input.nextInt();

        if(number == 176)
        {
                System.out.println("Yes");
        }
    }
}
```

The output says :

```
Your code has been evaluated against a set of test data.
You had 4 out of 5 tests pass correctly.

Double check your results in drJava and if you can't see what's wrong,
don't hesitate to start a post on Piazza.

Test 1, Decimal input but not 48.729: Passed!
Test 2, Decimal input but not 48.729: Passed!
Test 3, Decimal input but not 48.729: Passed!
Test 4, Integer input but not 48.729: Passed!
```

Not sure what the problem seems to be.

Comment: Based on the plain text of your test suite, it appears the input is being compared against `48.729` and not `176`.  Can you look into this?

Comment: sorry the output is actually :Your code has been evaluated against a set of test data.
You had 1 out of 2 tests pass correctly.

Double check your results in drJava and if you can't see what's wrong,
don't hesitate to start a post on Piazza.

Test 1, Integer input but not 176: Passed!
Test 2, Integer input is 176: Failed.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment is asking you to print out "YES" without the quotation marks. In your program it is only printing out "Yes" nothing is wrong with the code the issue is that you're printing "Yes" when it is asking for "YES" Simply just change "Yes" to "YES"